# PPP Network Detection for OSPF Demand Circuit Validation

Tags: network-programming, packet, pcap, ppp, ospf

I am looking for a way to detect if any incoming or outgoing network traffic is PPP (Point to Point). Is there a way that I can sniff for this type of traffic using the pcap library?

The reason I need to know if the traffic is PPP to validate a certain condition. That condition is if the DC (Demand-Circuit) bit in the Options Field of OSPF is enabled, then PPP must be enabled for that network. Only point-to-point networks receive the full benefit of OSPF Demand-Circuits (RFC 1793).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Point-to-point", in [RFC 1793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1793), doesn't refer to particular types of *traffic*, it refers to particular types of *networks*.  *All* traffic on, for example, a serial line running the Point-To-Point Protocol, is "point-to-point traffic"; *no* traffic on an Ethernet is "point-to-point".  Non-point-to-point traffic could be tunneled over a point-to-point network, and point-to-point traffic could be tunneled over a non-point-to-point network, but, in the case of a tunnel, there will often be a network interface (in the software sense, e.g. what `ifconfig -a` would list in most UN*X systems or `ipconfig/all` would list on Windows) for the tunneled traffic, in addition to a network interface for the lower-level network's adapter.

On most UN*Xes, you can use the `SIOCGIFFLAGS` ioctl to get the flags for a network interface, and one of those flags is the `IFF_POINTOPOINT` flag, which would indicate whether the network for that interface is a point-to-point network or not.

On Windows, I can't find an ioctl to get the flags for a specific interface, but the `SIO_GET_INTERFACE_LIST` [Winsock ioctl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will return an [INTERFACE_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure with an `iiFlags` member that includes the `IFF_POINTOPOINT` flag.